# NetworkStream.Read() and SSL

Tags: c#, networkstream

Was just wondering if anybody can look at the following code and explain to me why the length variable returns 0:

```
textToBeEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
txtEncryptedText = AESEncryption(textToBeEncrypted, key, true);
byte[] encText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtEncryptedText);

NetworkStream stream = s.GetStream();
stream.Write(encText, 0, PACKET_SIZE);

s.ReceiveTimeout = Timeout;

int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, PACKET_SIZE);
if (length == PACKET_SIZE)
{
    string decText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encText);
    txtDecryptedText = AESDecryption(decText, key, true);
    buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtDecryptedText);
    retval = Decode();
}
```

After I've encoded everything using AES, I'm writing out 1366 bytes of data in encText (PACKET_SIZE is 1036). I get no complaints regarding the Send; the data is sent out happily. When it tries to read it back in, however, length is always 0, meaning I don't get to enter the decode statement bracket. Any ideas? (retval is a string, before anyone asks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `length` is zero from this:

```
int length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, PACKET_SIZE);
```

it means the other machine has closed their outbound socket (your inbound socket), and no more data is ever going to be available.

You should also be very careful about this:

```
if (length == PACKET_SIZE)
{...}
```

There is **absolutely no guarantee** about what you read. What you *should* do here is buffer the data until you have an entire message (frame), and then process what you buffered. In particular, if the other end sends less than `PACKET_SIZE` bytes, your code is guaranteed to do nothing. Even if the other end sent *exactly* `PACKET_SIZE` bytes, it would be pretty unlikely to arrive in **exactly** a single chunk of `PACKET_SIZE` bytes.

For example:

```
int length;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
while((length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, length); // append what we just recieved

    // now: could check `ms` to see if we have a "frame" here...
}
//...or you could just process the entire recieved data here
```

Comment: Cheers, Marc. What's the easiest way of knowing how big the incoming data is, other than using length > 0?

Comment: @Skulmuk in advance? You absolutely **cannot** know that just from a stream, which is why many protocols take the pragmatic approach of prepending each message with the size of the next message, often as a network-byte-order int-32; you read the 4 byte header first, which tells you how much to buffer for the actual message; process the message; rinse; repeat. Another approach, common in text protocols, is to use CR/LF/CRLF as a framing token.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc. I'm still getting 0 bytes back, but I have a feeling that something's going on on the network at the moment. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @Skulmuk firewall is the first thing to check

Comment: meant to ask, does the fact that the buffer I'm writing out is bigger than the PACKET_SIZE variable make any difference (that's what stopped my Send method from crashing is all)? Cheers.